# needs its front tyres replacing/replaced

Tags: gerunds, participles

Is the following sentence okay with either "replacing" or "replaced"? If both options are correct, how do you analyze them?

> The car needs its front tyres replacing/replaced.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh Are you sure your English is idiomatic?

Comment: Both are acceptable. My feeling about the difference is that _replacing_ refers to the task of doing so ('needs someone to replace the tyres'), while _replaced_ refers to the tyres themselves (they need exchanging for new ones).

Comment: There's no discernable difference in meaning.

Comment: @Apollyon I did not even frame a sentence to be idiomatic or unidiomatic. Nevermind.